# Merging Multiple Tables into New Table in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, merge

I am looking to merge a number of individual tables into a new table in PostGIS. This is an easy task when working with Shapefile data, but I am unsure how to do this in PostGIS.

I think I use Append, but I am unsure even where to start.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming attributes are identical in all original tables and the geometry type is exactly the same in all tables, you can either

1. create the (empty) table first, then use INSERT INTO...SELECT... FROM to get all the data from each of the original tables into the merged one.
2. Create the new table from one big UNION statement.

For 1 it might go:

```
CREATE TABLE merged (id serial primary key, attrib1 integer, attrib2 varchar(15),....);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('merged','geom',<SRID>,'<FEATURE_TYPE>,'XY');
INSERT INTO merged (attrib1, attrib2, ...., geom) SELECT attribA, attribB,...,geom FROM table_1;
INSERT INTO merged (attrib1, attrib2, ...., geom) SELECT attribA, attribB,...,geom FROM table_2;
```

and so on...

For option 2:

```
CREATE TABLE merged AS( 
SELECT attribA, attribB,...,geom FROM table_1
UNION 
SELECT attribA, attribB,...,geom FROM table_2
UNION
.... 
);
SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('merged'::regclass);
```

Comment: Thank you Micha, I will try this.  Yes, all the tables have the same attribute and they are the same geometry type.

Thanks again...

Comment: I have tried and I am getting an error associated to the XY.  I know I am putting in the wrong thing, as I am unsure as to what I should be using there.  Here is my query and the output response.  Any help would be great.

Comment: CREATE TABLE pbear_pp (id serial primary key, entityname varchar(40));
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('pbear_pp','geom','-1','polygon','XY');
INSERT INTO pbear_pp(entityname, geom) SELECT entityname, geom FROM nts250k.nts250k_043e_poly;
INSERT INTO pbear_pp(entityname, geom) SELECT entityname, geom FROM nts250k.nts250k_043f_poly;
ETC ETC...

Comment: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "pbear_pp_id_seq" for serial column "pbear_pp.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "pbear_pp_pkey" for table "pbear_pp"
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "XY"

Comment: use 2 instead of 'XY' as that argument specifies the dimensions.

Comment: Thank you Micha, I tried the second option and it works nicely. I have a question: What does the last line mean? This one: 

SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('merged'::regclass);