# Merging vector layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, merge

I have dozens of vector layers that I want to join together in QGIS.

They have identical fields.

How do I do this?

Comment: You could also consider loading everything into PostGIS, SQL Server etc. and doing a chained insert into or union query. Very easy to do if you have identical fields plus it may be faster than the tool mentioned in the other question. See this question for more detail on that process: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27402/merge-multiple-tables-into-a-new-table-in-postgis

Answer (score 2):

Follow this menu path...

Vector -> Data management tools -> Merge shapefiles into one

Comment: Thanks, but that only appears to merge files within one folder.  I have many vector layers that correspond with many folders and I want to merge them all into one vector layer.  All the files in each folder have identical names too.  I am sorry if this duplicates a question already asked.  I guess I am not familiar enough with the jargon to be able to identify the same question asked in different words.  But as you can see I didn't get the answer I needed anyway.  Surely I can select the relevant layers and merge them somehow...