# Union PostGIS tables turns blank

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I have a simple tasks that regarding combining multiple Postgis tables. Let's say I have 4 tables called `tx_shape`, `ca_cd_1_shape`,`wy_shape`, and `ma_suffulk_co_shape`. Two of which are states, one is a congressional district, and another is a county.

I want to combine them into one giant shape table. I tried using referring to this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27402/merge-multiple-tables-into-a-new-table-in-postgis), and ran

```
CREATE TABLE merged AS (
SELECT gid, geom FROM tx_shape
UNION
SELECT gid, geom from wy_shape
UNION
SELECT gid, geom FROM ca_cd_1_shape
UNION
SELECT gid, geom FROM ma_suffolk_co_shape);
```

But all it returns is a blank. The gid are displaying correctly but when I export it using pgsql2shp with

```
pgsql2shp -f "test_output" -h localhost -u username -P password my_db "select * from merged"
```

All I get is a blank, am I missing something here? It should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Your `gid` column will likely not be unique.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to join 4 different geometries into a single shapefile, remember that the shapefiles only accept 1 kind of geometry (only points for instance). Also, PostGIS keeps a record of the tables geometries in the table 'geometry_columns'.

I recommend:

1. Create a new table with the specific geometry (for instance Point):

> CREATE TABLE newtable (gid integer NOT NULL, geom
>   geometry(Point,4326));

2. Populate it from the values from your tables:

> insert into newtable(gid, geom) select gid, geom from tx_shape; insert
>   into newtable(gid, geom) select gid, geom from ca_cd_1_shape; insert
>   into newtable(gid, geom) select gid, geom from wy_shape; insert into
>   newtable(gid, geom) select gid, geom from ma_suffulk_co_shape;

3. Export it as shapefile

pgsql2shp -f "test_output" -h localhost -u username -P password my_db newtable

Comment: What if there are no overlapping ids to merge? All my gids are mutually exclusive

Comment: Also wouldn't there be a merging conflict with multiple `gids`?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I assumed you need to use an unique id. If the gids are mutually exclusive only the ids from the first table will be show. Also, there would be a merging conflict. You just need to know that all the geometries your are joining have to be of the same class. I recommend to create a new table with a specific geometry (check the table geometry_columns) and populate it with the data from your 4 tables.

Comment: Gotcha, I tried another approach using `CREATE TABLE merged (geom geometry); INSERT INTO merged (geom) SELECT geom FROM tx_shape; INSERT INTO merge(geom) SELECT geom FROM ma_suffolk_co_shape;`  etc. but no luck.

Comment: Try to define the geometry: CREATE TABLE merged(
    gid integer NOT NULL,    
    geom geometry(Point,4326) 
);